# Last time the contact was modified

Tags: android, date, contacts

is there a way to find out the last time a contact was modified?
I can't seem to find a variable for it. The reason I'm asking is because I'd like to do a sync of the contacts to my web server and I don't feel like checking for each contact with a HTTP request if it needs updating.

So I was thinking to check the date of the last update to the date of the last sync.

Comment: No one knows? Or any way how I could find out which contacts were changed and which not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Didn't find a way to do this. I can store the last sync date, but no way of checking if the contact was updated since then.

EDIT:

the contact has a DIRTY flag, which is set to 1 if the contact was changed and not synced.

Answer (score 3):

I know its an old post, maybe help others...
There is a property calked CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP that you can use:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.html

> Timestamp (milliseconds since epoch) of when this contact was last updated. This includes updates to all data associated with this contact including raw contacts. Any modification (including deletes and inserts) of underlying contact data are also reflected in this timestamp.
>
> Constant Value: "contact_last_updated_timestamp"

Comment: When you call (or receive a call from) a contact, the values at: ContactsContract.Contact.TIMES_CONTACTED, ContactsContract.Contact.LAST_TIME_CONTACTED change. As a result, CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP is updated too

Comment: Not reliable dont use this

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs, you might also be able to cache `ContactsContract.Contacts.Entity.VERSION` yourself (for the different raw contacts which are associated with a contact) and compare it to the current values in the Android's content provider.