# Android - Get date added for contacts

Tags: android, android-contacts

Can I get the date added for each contacts in android ? 
I searched about it, but I didn't found anything

Answer (score 0):

I think is not possible, but you can get the version of the Contacts list

```
ContactsContract.Contacts.Entity.VERSION
```

and compare it to the current values in the Android's content provider.

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005932/last-time-the-contact-was-modified)

Comment: mmmmmmmm, Getting the version contacts can't help me, anyway thank you.